# SQL JOIN on Concatenated Column without CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, string-concatenation

So one table has the ID broken into two parts SYMBOL and NUMBER, the table i want to join it to has the SYMBOL and NUMBER combined to form the ID

Below is what I've come up with which obviously doesn't work... what would i need to do to join on a concatenated column without doing a CREATE TABLE?

```
Select
    concat(a.SYMBOL, ' ', a.NBR) AS 'ID', 
    a.Date, 
    b.Cost
From
    Identities a  
Join
    Financials b 
        On **concat(a.SYMBOL, ' ', a.NBR) AS 'ID'** = b.ID
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier could not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "as" the result of a function used in a join. You only "as" something to give a column an alias in a SELECT block

```
Select 
  b.ID, -- can use b.id here because it is equal
  a.Date, 
  b.Cost
From Identities a
Join Financials b On concat(a.SYMBOL, ' ', a.NBR) = b.ID
```